# update the UI thread from third part object in android

Tags: android, user-interface

I am dealing with this issue a couple of days now, that's why I took the decision to ask for a help.

I have the following simple android app which it consists of
Tha MainActivity, MyService and another class ShowSomething.

What I want to do is, when the service is trigerred by the main activity it creates an object ShowSomething and then I want to update the UI.

In all this process I want to use Handler and Messenger.

I quote the code and I appreciate if someone can help with what is mising from my code in order to work as I've described.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    Handler resultHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG,"Started");
        resultHandler = new HandlerExtension();
        Intent service_intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(service_intent);

    }

    class HandlerExtension extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"handle Message");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    // Handler that receives messages from the thread
    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
            // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
            try {
                ShowSomething smth = new ShowSomething();
                smth.publishProgress(4);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Restore interrupt status.
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
            // the service in the middle of handling another job
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
        // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

ShowSomething.java

```
public class ShowSomething
{
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    public ShowSomething(){}

    public void publishProgress(int randNum) {
        Log.v(TAG, "reporting back from the Random Number Thread");
        String text = "DemoStr";
        Bundle msgBundle = new Bundle();
        msgBundle.putString("result", text);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setData(msgBundle);
        Handler resultHandler = new Handler();
        resultHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```